# C++ Error, visual studio 2008, ERROR #C2679

Tags: c++

Hello world of stackoverflow, currently, i have a problem, im working on a school project for c++, to reset a high score file, however, when compiling, the compiler always shows this error:

error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string [100]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

so, after tons of googling, nothing works, so i just came here

here's my header:

```
//Include Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <string.h>

//use namespace std
using namespace std;
```

i clearly include string, iostream, fstream, and anything else i should need to include

here's my code:

```
void reset ()
{
//Declare Local Variables
int High_Score[5];
bool defualt;
char User_Reset = false;
string YN[100];
string High_Score_Name[5];
int Rank;

//Initialize a high score at 0
High_Score[4] = 0;

// Input the high scores from a file
ifstream Input_High_Scores;
Input_High_Scores.open ("High_Scores.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Input_High_Scores >> High_Score[i];
    Input_High_Scores >> High_Score_Name[i];
}
Input_High_Scores.close ();

//Welcome and ask the user if he wants to see high scores before resseting
cout << "Welcome to the High Score Reset Software" << endl;
cout << "Would you like to see your high scores before resettings? (0 for no, 1 for yes)" << endl;
cin >> YN;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string YN[100];
```

Here you are declaring an *array of 100 strings*. That's probably not what you wanted. Try:

```
string YN;
```

The error message you got is referring to the line

```
cin >> YN;
```

where, if `YN` is an array of 100 strings, the `>>` operator has no idea what you want to do. However, `>>` knows how to read *one* string.

Comment: ah, thanks, that was it, figures that it's something so simple though